What do we mean by "philosophy "? Can anything be a subject of philosophy?
At what point does philosophy become physics or psychology or something else?  Can there be, for example, a "philosophy of dogs"?  I'm guessing not, because it is too narrow, but because dogs are beings, such a "philosophy" might be a subset of ontology.
How do we connect philosophy to other -ologies?  Or does it, like so many academic sciences, exist in an impenetrable silo?  How for example, does a Western philosopher relate to an Eastern philosopher, or a positivist to an existentialist, or a philosopher to a natural scientist or to a historian or professor of literature?

Yes, we may have philosophy of everything: philosophy is asking questions more than producing answers. Typically, when we have the solution to a problem, this is no more philosophy but science.
